# Clone Partition (OS Partition) Differential?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, windows-server-2016

I am looking for software to do the following:

1. Copy the partition highlighted in yellow to the same disk(another parition) (imagine there's enough space unallocated)
2. Perform incremental/differential copies when rerun

Other preferences would be:

1. Software does not require much manual intervention. (can be scripted or scheduled, or 1 button clicked)

I'm asking this for a specific use case:

1. I need the ability to "snapshot" a physical machine OS drive. In this case there is one application being updated/upgraded on a cycle. (Software = Commvault Media Agent)
2. I believe this will be quicker than performing a restore of the server from backup. Since I could just modify boot partition and restart the server.

[image: DISK COPY]

EDIT:
I have looked into containers; and believe this very much may provide a solution for quick rollback. The problem is at the moment; that I need to passthrough Tape Library directly connected to the machine. I'm not sure at the moment if this is possible.

Comment: This is basically what any backup package will do. full+dif. You do realise a backup to the same drive doesn't qualify as 'safe'?

Comment: @Tetsujin - Yes, its not so much as a backup as we have backups for servers stored offsite (disk and tape). This server is specifically part of the backup software itself, meaning no data on it is critical. It can be rebuilt. This solution was thought of as a "physical" snapshot. To quickly roll it back if their was a problem with the software upgrade.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Think of it as a last known good. Except that I can just reboot the server and have it up and running in minutes rather than a full disk restore via backup. Cant find any software that does this at the moment. Well not to the same disk (another partition). I would just copy to another disk (but we have already setup the RAID on mirror on the two OS disks. :(